# Can't import Gluon into mma

Tags: import, neural-networks, mxnet-format

This is a simple DNN from [Fast, portable neural networks with Gluon HybridBlocks](http://gluon.mxnet.io/chapter07_distributed-learning/hybridize.html):

This is [json file](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/model.json) and [params file](http://home.ustc.edu.cn/~xiaozh/SE/model.params) of Gluon(MXNet)

```
import mxnet as mx
from mxnet.gluon import nn
print("mxnet version: "+mx.__version__)

mx.random.seed(1234)  #Getting the same result everytime
def get_net():
    # construct a MLP
    net = nn.HybridSequential()
    with net.name_scope():
        net.add(nn.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
        net.add(nn.Dense(128, activation="relu"))
        net.add(nn.Dense(2))
    # initialize the parameters
    net.collect_params().initialize()
    return net

# forward
x = mx.nd.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3]])
net = get_net()
net.hybridize()
print('=== net(x) ==={}'.format(net(x)))

from mxnet import sym
x = sym.var('data')
net(x).save('model.json')
net.collect_params().save('model.params')

##############   Re-importing the net  ##############
sym = mx.symbol.load('model.json') 
nd = mx.nd.load('model.params')
inputND = mx.nd.array([[0.1,0.2,0.3]])
nd["data"] = inputND
e = sym.bind(mx.cpu(), nd)
out = e.forward()
print(out[0])
```

> mxnet version: 0.11.1
>
> === net(x) ===
>
> [[ 0.00051653 -0.00040585]]
>
> [[ 0.00051653 -0.00040585]]

In Mathematica11.2,this code will **crash the kernel**,I think because mma use old version of MXNet.At that time,there isn't gluon actually, a new interface of MXNet.

```
Import["model.json","MXNet"]
```

And this code also can't work

```
<< NeuralNetworks`;
net = ImportMXNetModel["model.json", "model.params"];
```

Comment: Links do not work.

Comment: @b.gatessucks fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Bug fixed in 11.3.0**

```
net = Import[
             "C:\\Users\\xzhou\\Desktop\\mxnet_prediction\\SE\\model.json", 
             "MXNet"]
net[{0.1, 0.2, 0.3}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> In Mathematica 11.2, this code will crash the kernel, I think because mma use old version of MXNet

This hypothesis is correct. I have verified that this works for internal 11.3 builds which use the latest version of MXNet, so it will automatically be fixed when 11.3 is released. It is a bug though that it crashes the kernel. Have reported this.

Comment: Yes,MMA use version 0.9.5.But MXNet  has released the 0.12.0

Comment: MXNet support the new function`export` to export the net that make it easy using MXNet in C++